# Weird Implicit Differentiation

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

While solving the sums from my textbook on implicit differentiation, I happened to encounter a sum :

$$
Y^3 + XY + X^2 = 0
$$

and I was suppose to find dY/dX and substitute the value 10 for X after differentiating. Weirdly enough, this equation does not let me get rid of the variable Y after solving and hence I couldn't find a valid answer.

Would request you to help me approach the problem.
Also, I would like to do so without finding the roots of Y and solving, as someone pointed out earlier in class.

Sorry for the aweful quality.

Comment: Solve first $Y^3 + 10Y + 10^2 = 0$.

Comment: Would like to know why I should do this?

Comment: @TotalAnimeImmersion Because if do, you will have $Y(10)$. You can then use $Y(10)$ to solve the equation for $Y'(10)$.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand, can u point me out in the correct direction from the basics. Something like a graphical explanation would be really nice although its too much to ask for :)

Comment: You said that you couldn't get rid of the variable $Y$. So you can get past this by finding the value of $Y$, which you know since $Y$ is related to $X$ by the equation you gave, and $X = 10$.

Comment: In this particular case, you can indeed solve for $Y$, as hinted at in the other comments and done in detail in the answer by Claude. However, you should know that in general, you cannot expect to be able to solve for $Y$ analytically, so it is normal for the answer to contain $Y$. There is nothing weird about that at all.

Comment: Ok, and how do I go about it if I'm not provided with the value of X?

Comment: Then you get an answer depending on both $X$ and $Y$. You may or may not be able to simpify the answer using the original equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F=y^3+x y+x^2$. Then $$F'_x=y+2x$$ $$F'_y=3y^2+x$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=-\frac{y+2x}{3y^2+x}$$ We know $x=10$ and we need the corresponding $y$ which is the solution of $y^3+10y+100=0$ which is cubic equation that you can solve using Cardano. This equation has a single real root given by $$y=\frac{\sqrt[3]{10 \left(\sqrt{2055}-45\right)}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{10^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{3
   \left(\sqrt{2055}-45\right)}}\simeq -3.93003$$ If you do not use Cardano, only a numerical method could be used. The simplest would be Newton, which, starting from a "reason
able" guess $y_0$ will update it according to $$y_{n+1}=y_n-\frac{f(y_n)}{f'(y_n)}$$ with $f(y)=y^3+10y+100$. By inspection, you could see that there is a root close to $-4$; so, let us select $y_0=-4$. Soo, Newton iterates will be $-3.93103$,$-3.93003$.

Comment: What if the value of X wasn't given, how would I then get rid of Y? And thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Well, if $x$ is not given, you just have $y'$ as a function of $x$ and $y$. If $y$ is given, you get $x$ solving the quadratic.

Comment: It actually tells you to substitute the value of X after finding dY/dX. My point is, in the previous questions there were values of X mentioned to be substituted after finding dY/dX. Could I just substitute the value of X first and then solve for dY/dX?

Answer (score 0):

$$Y^3 + XY + X^2 = 0$$
$$3Y^2dY+YdX+XdY+2XdX=0$$
$$(3Y^2+X)dY=-(Y+2X)dX$$
$$\frac{dY}{dX}=-\frac{Y+2X}{3Y^2+X}$$
Are you sure that you need more ? If yes, you will have to solve $Y^3 + XY + X^2 = 0$ for $Y$ and put it back into the above formula.